# Why my Intent is not working?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I click on Signin Button, App is Crashing. While I am debugging the code, it moves to a finally block of "Looper.java" file. I don't have any file with this name.

MainActivity.java

```
private void signIn() {

   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main_Tab.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_home);
}
```

Looper.java

```
try {
            msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);
        } finally {
            if (traceTag != 0) {
                Trace.traceEnd(traceTag);
            }
        }
```

Comment: [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) is part of Android

Comment: can you please tell me why its redirecting me to that file ?

Comment: Firstly, it is not a concern that your code on debugging is taking you to `Looper`. In plain java, `main` function is entry point into the code but in Android there are many core files which call your code. E.g. when you override `Activity.onCreate`, there should be some code calling your `Activity.onCreate`. So when you debug code flow will reach that file. Same is case with Looper to put simply.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't have added the activity (Main_Tab) to your AndroidManifest.xml file
I faced the same issue and it was resolved upon doing this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main_Tab.class);
    startActivity(intent);    
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15416876)

Answer (score 0):

The below line should be before starting the activity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_home);
```

because when you run new activity, new content will be displayed instead of old one.
it should be like this.

```
private void signIn() {
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_home);
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main_Tab.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: Sorry. But the same error. But this time, instead of sending me to looper.java , its redirecting me to intent.java while debugging.

Comment: Yes. I did. I did Everything but the app keeps on crashing.

Comment: did you `setcontentview` in your `MainActivity onCreate`?

Comment: Sir, If I wouldn't have, my main activity won't be starting at the first place.

Comment: give me all of you code and i promise to compile it myself and give the results back to you but with this amount of info i am guessing what's wrong

Comment: sir give me your facebook id i ll send you request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137266/discussion-between-mehran-zamani-and-varun-pandey).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main_Tab.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Try this, don't call setContentView method after starting the activity.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()` method always put these two lines on top -

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

So, all you need in `onClickListener()`, in this case which is `signIn()` are these.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main_Tab.class);
startActivity(intent)
```

If the app is still crashing, debug `onCreate()` method of `Main_Tab` and post the log report.

Comment: This is am getting RED in event Log
7:47:33 PM InvalidVirtualFileAccessException: Accessing invalid virtual file: file://D:/android studio workspace/NIDHIIOT/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/multidex-instrumentation/1.0.1/res; original:267030; found:-

Comment: Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: In Andriod Studio go to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart->Invalidate and Restart the Android Studio. Also clean and rebuilt your project.

Answer (score 0):

Change your sign in constructor to this

```
private void signIn() {

Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main_Tab.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
```

and in your onCreate constructor add this if not there already.

```
final Context context = this;
```

Let me know if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Main_Tab.class extends some kind of Activity class such as "AppCompatActivity". One thing that also caught my eyes is your usage of underscore in Main_Tab, but I guess it's my personal preference to use camelcase for naming classes.

Also try removing:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_home);
```

Comment: Yes sir. Main_Tab class extends AppCompactActivity